# Semantics of std::initializer_list

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

I'm implementing a collection of intrusive containers trying to be Standard Library like as possible. I'm considering whether I should support [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) but I don't quite grasp its semantics.

Basically if I had this code:

```
std::string a = "a";
std::string b = "b";
std::string c = "c";

std::initializer_list<std::string> list = { a, b, c };

// pass list to a container or whatever
```

Are the objects passed from the initializer list actual copies or "references" to the strings `a`, `b` and `c`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well that was a nice failure, with flames and smoke and all. And, it's the second time I get this wrong. I hate initializer_lists :<

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this `std::initializer_list` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list):

> An object of type `std::initializer_list<T>` is a lightweight proxy object that provides access to an array of objects of type `const T`.

What that means is that objects in the initializer list is stored by *value*. So to answer your question, yes copies will be made.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit NZ slang for cool, sweet as, thanks etc.